# Edit SetParameters

Tags: visual-studio, iis, msbuild, webdeploy

I am trying to use the webdeploy cmd file created using the MSBuild WebDeploy packager.

It creates a XXX.SetParameters.xml file (as seen below).

I am attempting to control the destination directory of where it creates the web application.  But I can't get it to work.

I am calling the .cmd with just "/Y"

But, it always create the content in c:\inetpub\wwwroot

What should I have in my SetParameters.xml file in order to do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <parameters>
        <setParameter value="Default Web Site" name="IIS Web Application Name"/>
        <setParameter value="Server=sqlserver;Database=CodeCamper;Integrated Security=true" name="CodeCamper-Web.config Connection String"/>
        <setParameter value="C:\MyFolder\CCWeb" name="physicalPathLocation"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are deploying the package to the Default Web Site in IIS. That site is created by default by IIS.  You can go into IIS and change the path or create a new site to a new path and then deploy to that site by changing the "IIS Web Application Name" to match the new site's name.

If you don't really care about IIS and just want to deploy the site to a specific directory you can create a custom manifest:

SetParameters File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sitemanifest>
  <IisApp path="C:\temp\manualPackageDeploymentDir" />
</sitemanifest>
```

MSDeploy call:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package=WebApplication7.zip -dest:manifest=WebApplication7.DestManifest.xml
```

This is all detailed in the following post under the "Manually Deploy a Package" section - https://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/25/the-anatomy-of-a-webdeploy-package/

Comment: Thanks.  What I was really attempting to do was deploy to a subdirectory under that site.  I believe the correct way (if using the .cmd file) is:
    <setParameter value="Default Web Site/DirectoryName" name="IIS Web Application Name"/>

Comment: If this helped answer your question please don't forget to mark it as the answer and up vote it.  Thanks!